# Помогите сохранить состояние checkbox

Tags: java, android

делаю систему лайков и хочу узнать как сохранить состояние checkbox в RecyclerView.Adapter...

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int mShowStyle;
    VKPostArray obj;
     ....

    public PostAdapter(Context context, VKPostArray posts, VKApiUser user, int showStyle) {
        super();
        this.obj = posts;
        this.mainUser = user;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mShowStyle = showStyle;
        ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PostViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        p = obj.get(position);

        holder.textPost.setText(p.text);

        holder.like1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Лайк поставлен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Лайк снят", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }}
        });
        holder.textlikePost.setText("" + p.likes_count);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return obj.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (mShowStyle == NineGridImageView.STYLE_FILL) {

            return new PostViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_wall, parent, false));
        } else {
            return new PostViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_wall, parent, false));
        }}


    public class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        TextView textPost;
        CheckBox like1;

        public PostViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_wall);
            textPost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPost);

            like1 = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_like_button);

        }
    }
```

код Активити:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    String[] scopes = new String[]{VKScope.FRIENDS, VKScope.WALL, VKScope.OFFLINE};
    private long back_pressed;
    private ProgressBar prog;
    VKApiUser mainUser;
    Button loginVK;
    FloatingActionButton buttontop;
    Context context;
    Picasso picasso;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;
    VKPostArray posts;
    TextView txtex;
    ImageView im;
    private VKApiPhoto photo;
    VKList<VKApiUser> userMe;
    ArrayList<String> imgUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    RelativeLayout mainLayout;
    RelativeLayout mainLayout1;
    RecyclerView rv;
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    PostAdapter mNineImageAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        prog = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prog);
        prog.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

        loginVK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        buttontop = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_top);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

        ConnectivityManager cn = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo nf = cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (nf != null && nf.isConnected() == true) {

            if (!VKSdk.isLoggedIn()) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.aurorize, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                mainLayout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout_id);
                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, mainLayout1, false);
                swipeContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mainLayout1.addView(view);

            } else {

                VKRequest reqWall = VKApi.wall().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID, ..., VKApiConst.EXTENDED, 1, VKApiConst.COUNT, 100, "text"));
                reqWall.setPreferredLang("ru");
                reqWall.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                        super.onComplete(response);

                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.json;
                        String owner = null;
                        try {
                            owner = (((JSONObject) ((JSONArray) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("response")).get("items")).get(0)).getString("owner_id"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        posts = new VKPostArray();
                        try {
                            posts.parse(response.json);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        photo = new VKApiPhoto();
                        try {
                            photo.parse(response.json);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            JSONArray array = ((JSONArray) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("response")).get("groups"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            VKApiPost post = posts.get(0);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.userWall);
                        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

                        mNineImageAdapter = new PostAdapter(MainActivity.this, posts, mainUser, NineGridImageView.STYLE_GRID);
                        rv.setAdapter(mNineImageAdapter);
                        mNineImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        if (rv != null)
                            prog.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }
                });
            }
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.not_internet_please, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout_id);
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lenta, mainLayout, false);
            swipeContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mainLayout.addView(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Нажмите еще раз для выхода...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
            if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
                    // Пользователь успешно авторизовался
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Авторизация прошла успешно!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(VKError error) {
                    // Произошла ошибка авторизации (например, пользователь запретил авторизацию)
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ошибка авторизации....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // сохраняем значения в Preferences в виде строки с JSON
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String values = preferences.getString("checkbox_values", gson.toString());

        if (values != null) {
            Type curValuesType = new TypeToken<Boolean[]>() {}.getType();
            boolean[] currentValues = gson.fromJson(values, curValuesType);
            mNineImageAdapter.setCurrentValues(currentValues);
        }}

        @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // восстанавливаем значения в чекбоксах из Preferences
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String values = gson.toJson(mNineImageAdapter.getCurrentValues());
        preferences.edit().putString("checkbox_values", values).apply();

    }}
```

После того как исправил на то что мне ответили, начала выбиваться ошибка при запуске приложения:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {calculation.material.oma.sviter.by/calculation.material.oma.sviter.by.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void calculation.material.oma.sviter.by.PostAdapter.setCurrentValues(boolean[])' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void calculation.material.oma.sviter.by.PostAdapter.setCurrentValues(boolean[])' on a null object reference
at calculation.material.oma.sviter.by.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:488)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1258)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6327)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Comment: вы хотите хранить состояния чекбоксов на какой срок.. только на время скролинга, переворота девайса или до повторного запуска приложения?

Comment: ну поставил лайк! закрыл приложение и при открытии что бы checkbox сохранил свое состояние

Comment: можешь сохранять состояние в SharedPreferences

[1]: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php

Answer (score 1):

Можно сохранить значения в `Preferences`. Для этого нужно добавить массив `boolean`, который будем сохранять.

Необходимо доработать Ваш адаптер и активити или фрагмент, в котором у Вас `RecyclerView`.

Примерный код адаптера:

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder> {

    private boolean[] currentValues; // добавим массив значений для сохранения
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int mShowStyle;
    VKPostArray obj;
     ....

    public PostAdapter(Context context, VKPostArray posts, VKApiUser user, int showStyle) {
        super();
        this.obj = posts;
        this.mainUser = user;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mShowStyle = showStyle;
        ctx = context;

        // инициализируем массив 
        this.currentValues = new boolean[posts.size()];
    }

    // добавим метод get для нашего массива значений
    public boolean[] getCurrentValues() {
        return currentValues;
    }

    // добавим метод set для нашего массива значений
    public void setCurrentValues(boolean[] currentValues) {
        this.currentValues = currentValues;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PostViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        p = obj.get(position);

        holder.textPost.setText(p.text);

        // устанавливаем чекбокс из массива
        holder.like1.setChecked(currentValues[position]);

        holder.like1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                // сохраняем изменяемое значение в массив
                currentValues[position] = isChecked;

                if (isChecked) {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Лайк поставлен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Лайк снят", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }}
        });
        holder.textlikePost.setText("" + p.likes_count);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return obj.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (mShowStyle == NineGridImageView.STYLE_FILL) {

            return new PostViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_wall, parent, false));
        } else {
            return new PostViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_wall, parent, false));
        }}


    public class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        TextView textPost;
        CheckBox like1;

        public PostViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_wall);
            textPost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPost);

            like1 = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_like_button);

    }
 }
```

В активити:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    String[] scopes = new String[]{VKScope.FRIENDS, VKScope.WALL, VKScope.OFFLINE};
    private long back_pressed;
    private ProgressBar prog;
    VKApiUser mainUser;
    Button loginVK;
    FloatingActionButton buttontop;
    Context context;
    Picasso picasso;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;
    VKPostArray posts;
    TextView txtex;
    ImageView im;
    private VKApiPhoto photo;
    VKList<VKApiUser> userMe;
    ArrayList<String> imgUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    RelativeLayout mainLayout;
    RelativeLayout mainLayout1;
    RecyclerView rv;
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private Gson gson;
    PostAdapter mNineImageAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.gson = new Gson();
        this.preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        prog = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prog);
        prog.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

        loginVK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        buttontop = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_top);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

        ConnectivityManager cn = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo nf = cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (nf != null && nf.isConnected() == true) {

            if (!VKSdk.isLoggedIn()) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.aurorize, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                mainLayout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout_id);
                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, mainLayout1, false);
                swipeContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mainLayout1.addView(view);

            } else {

                VKRequest reqWall = VKApi.wall().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID, ..., VKApiConst.EXTENDED, 1, VKApiConst.COUNT, 100, "text"));
                reqWall.setPreferredLang("ru");
                reqWall.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                        super.onComplete(response);

                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.json;
                        String owner = null;
                        try {
                            owner = (((JSONObject) ((JSONArray) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("response")).get("items")).get(0)).getString("owner_id"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        posts = new VKPostArray();
                        try {
                            posts.parse(response.json);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        photo = new VKApiPhoto();
                        try {
                            photo.parse(response.json);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            JSONArray array = ((JSONArray) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("response")).get("groups"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            VKApiPost post = posts.get(0);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.userWall);
                        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

                        mNineImageAdapter = new PostAdapter(MainActivity.this, posts, mainUser, NineGridImageView.STYLE_GRID);
                        rv.setAdapter(mNineImageAdapter);
                        setCheckBoxFromPrefs();

                        if (rv != null)
                            prog.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }
                });
            }
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.not_internet_please, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout_id);
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lenta, mainLayout, false);
            swipeContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mainLayout.addView(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Нажмите еще раз для выхода...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
            if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
                    // Пользователь успешно авторизовался
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Авторизация прошла успешно!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(VKError error) {
                    // Произошла ошибка авторизации (например, пользователь запретил авторизацию)
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ошибка авторизации....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // восстанавливаем значения в чекбоксах из Preferences
        if (mNineImageAdapter != null) {
             setCheckBoxFromPrefs();
        }
    }

        @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // сохраняем значения в Preferences в виде строки с JSON
        String values = gson.toJson(mNineImageAdapter.getCurrentValues());
        preferences.edit().putString("checkbox_values", values).apply();

    }

    private void setCheckBoxFromPrefs() {
        String values = preferences.getString("checkbox_values", null);

        if (values != null) {
            Type curValuesType = new TypeToken<boolean[]>() {}.getType();
            boolean[] currentValues = gson.fromJson(values, curValuesType);
            mNineImageAdapter.setCurrentValues(currentValues);
        }
    }


 }
```

Comment: А Gson gson = new Gson(); это пример?

Comment: @sviter-pro с помощью [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) я сериализую массив в `String`, чтобы сохранить его в `Preferences`. Вы можете использовать любой другой вариант сохранения массива в `Preferences`.

Comment: выбивает ошибку при запуске приложения. обновил статью.

Comment: @sviter-pro не инициализирован массив, поправил ответ

Comment: все овно ошибка... ошибку обновил...

Comment: @sviter-pro Это уже совсем другая ошибка. Проверяйте почему у Вас объект `SharedPreferences` = null. Вы не показали код Вашей активити\фрагмена, где Вы инициализируете `SharedPreferences`, поэтому подсказать, что-то невозможно.

Comment: Внес код своей активити

Comment: @sviter-pro В методе `onCreate` пронициализируйте `preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: отлично, так запустилось! но вот когда я поставил лайк и убил приложение, а затем заново его запустил, то посыпалась ошибка!!! Ошибку обновил...

Comment: @sviter-pro Опечатался в коде, конечно должно быть `Type curValuesType = new TypeToken<boolean[]>() {}.getType();`. Исправил ответ.

Comment: опять, когда я поставил лайк и убил приложение, а затем заново его запустил, то посыпалась ошибка!!! Ошибку обновил...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48425/discussion-between-mit-and-sviter-pro).